# Create a collection linked to user ID in Firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Type of App to give context: An app that enables wedding bands to create a profile. Part of this profile will be to enter different dates with locations (Events)and return them in a list view. I have a Firestore collection called `userData`. The collection is made up of documents `IDs`(Firebase User ids) generated during sign in. These documents contain fields, mainly `Strings` and `arrays`for things like a header image.I'm thinking of creating a class called `Events` with member variables `date` and `venue`. I'm wondering how I should structure Firestore to allow the Events be queried and returned in a listView. I've looked at `sub collections` where the UserData would be a parent but I'm not sure is this possible? Or maybe creating a collection at the root called Events but not sure how'd I'd connect the different bands to their `Events`. Here is a screen shot of Firestore. Each document is a band. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Use a new top-level collection to store all events, with a field for the id of the band to help with querying for events for only that bad.
2. Use a subcollection under each band for their events.

It's totally up to you to choose.  It will depend on the kinds of queries you want to make.  Note that if you go with #2, you will not be able to query for events across bands (at least not until Firestore supports collection group queries which it does not today).